# What is the difference between unsigned long & unsigned int and how should these 2 types be marshaled in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, c

So, i was "translating" a couple structs from C/C++ into C# and came across something that i don't really understand...

Here is the first struct:

```
typedef struct _MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD {
COORD dwMousePosition;
DWORD dwButtonState;
DWORD dwControlKeyState;
DWORD dwEventFlags;
}
```

which i wrote as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MouseEventRecord
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    public Coord dwMousePosition; //struct with (short X) & (short Y)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public ButtonState dwButtonState; //A uint enum
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public ControlKeyState dwControlKeyState; //A uint enum
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public MouseEventFlags dwEventFlags; //A uint enum
}
```

And then there is this struct:

```
typedef struct _CONSOLE_READCONSOLE_CONTROL {
    ULONG nLength;
    ULONG nInitialChars;
    ULONG dwCtrlWakeupMask;
    ULONG dwControlKeyState;
}
```

which i wrote as:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ConsoleReadConsoleControl
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint nLength;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint nInitialChars;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint dwCtrlWakeupMask;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public ControlKeyState dwControlKeyState; //A uint enum
    }
```

Now, i am not sure if this is correct, the reason i wrote `ULONG` as `public uint` is because `ULONG` (which is intern `unsigned long`) is 4 bytes in size (did sizeof(unsigned long) & sizeof(unsigned int) both of which returned 4) but then, what is the difference between `DWORD (unsigned int)` & `ULONG (unsigned long)` if they both are 4 bytes in size? And are the "translated" structs written correctly?

I did read in the GNU documentation that `unsigned long` depends on the systems architecture so, `unsigned long` can be 64-bits, same as `unsigned long long int`. I don't quite understand this because my PC is running 64-bit Windows so, shouldn't `sizeof(unsigned long)` have returned 8 and not 4?

Comment: Indeed sizeof(unsigned long) should have returned you 8 if you are on a 64-bit system. You probably compiled it for a 32-bit system target.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois - not if he is on a Windows box, where `long` is 32-bit - even for a 64bit program.

Comment: Windows still uses a 32 bit long on 64 bit systyems.  *Nix uses a 64 bit long on 64 bit systems.  If you want known width types in C++ use the `intNN_t` types where `NN` is the bit width.

Comment: @MartinBonner Ok I didn't know it! I'm used to coding only on Unix systems.

Comment: @MartinBonner Windows Box? First time i hear of it, i got windows via the media creation tool (found on MS's website)

Comment: "Box" = computer, PC, machine.  In other words, "if you are running a Windows system" (which you obviously are, because those types are from the Windows API).

Comment: There is no difference, compilers that generate code for Windows use the [LLP64 data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models). Mostly an historical accident, Windows started at 16-bits so there is a lot of `long` around.  LLP64 was the easiest way to provide portability.

Comment: I think that part of your problem is you told it to marshal dwMousePosition as LPStruct.  In _MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD, dwMousePosition is a COORD, not a pointer to a COORD.

Comment: @OldFart then what should it be marshaled as? Or should it not be marshaled as anything?

Answer (score 1):

This is confusing.

Firstly, on Windows there is no difference between `unsigned long` and `unsigned int` (except that they are different types, so you can overload functions on them).  Your marshalling code is fine.

On most other platforms, `int` is 32 bits, `long long` is 64 bits, and `long` is 32-bits in a 32-bit program and 64-bits in a 64-bit program.  (In the this case, IntPtr would be a suitable marshalling declaration - it switches size correctly).

Comment: And back in the 16bit days, `int` was 16 bits and `long` was 32 bits. The C and C++ standard have never defined the exact bit sizes for integer types, they are always implementation specific. The standard only guarantees that `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)` and the same for the corresponding `unsigned` types.

Comment: When marshalling a method that takes a pointer-sized integer (e.g. a long on Unix which might be 32 or 64 bits), you can/should use IntPtr in C#. That allows you to keep your assembly AnyCPU while supporting both 32-bit and 64-bit environments.

Comment: @Zastal : Ooh!  Good point.  I'll amend (even if it might have problems on 128 bit platforms - I don't expect to see any of those for 50 years).